# Move mouse to specified point

Tags: c#, winforms, mouse, mousemove

I'd like to make a c# app that moves the mouse to a specified x,y position on the screen. I've tried a few codes I found online but none seem to work.

Comment: If you're looking for a quick and short script, there are languages better suited for this, such as AutoIt

Comment: no i need it to be c# so i can integrate it into another app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = new Point { X = xxx, Y = yyy };
```

Or try to use the native WinAPI for XP (or earlier):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern long SetCursorPos(int x, int y);

public void SetCursorPosition(Point p)
{
    SetCursorPos(p.X, p.Y);
}
```

Comment: That's awesome! But it doesn't seem to work with xp :-(